# cmd cd is not able to find directory

Tags: cmd

I have a folder :

```
Y:\GOA Ticketing\Daily Productivity\Quality Control\Duplicate & High Value Transactions Report
```

I open cmd. Enter

```
y:
```

Then I run:

```
cd Y:\GOA Ticketing\Daily Productivity\Quality Control\Duplicate & High Value Transactions Report
```

This gives me an error : The system cannot find the path specified.
'High' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The folder is present there.
I even did:

```
dir
```

in Y:\GOA Ticketing\Daily Productivity\Quality Control>. It lists Duplicate & High Value Transactions Report folder as a

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please move your question to superuser.com - it is not related to programming after all

Comment: The command line is incorrect. The correct command line is `cd /D "Y:\GOA Ticketing\Daily Productivity\Quality Control\Duplicate & High Value Transactions Report"`. Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help. There is explained the file/folder name completion feature and there is described on last output help page in last paragraph that a file/folder name (or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` (or `<>|`) must be enclosed in `"` to get characters interpreted literally.

Comment: If you want to know how the character `&` is interpreted outside a double quoted argument string by the *Windows Command Processor*, see [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) and the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)). I recommend reading also [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Comment: If you want to see file/folder name completion in action and learn from `cmd` how to correct specify file/folder argument strings, then open a command prompt window, type `C:\Pro` and press key __TAB__. Look what is displayed now. Press again __TAB__ and see how the folder path changes. Press once more __TAB__ and another folder path is displayed, now without surrounding `"`. Press once more __TAB__ and continue typing with `\Int` and press again __TAB__. See how `cmd` extends the folder path and moves second `"` from the middle to the end of the folder path.

Answer (score 2):

please try to put the path with in quotes and try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).